# AWGN model of Quantization Noise

Tags: noise, quantization

**[Edit answer moved from OP edit to "Answers" as per comment suggestion]**

I'm trying to create a simple model of a signal chain (image sensor) that includes an ADC but I'm failing to observe quantization noise. I'm afraid I'm missing big points about quantization noise. [Will assume Matlab for pseudo code]

Let's assume that the input signal has a range between 0-1 Volts and the ADC has N bits with `LSB=1/2^N` (eg 8 or 10).

My input signal average is centered in the range and let's assume that the standard deviation is a certain percentage of the ADC LSB (alpha):
`I=0.5+alpha*LSB*randn(10000,1)`

I'm modeling the ADC as a quantizer like so:
`Iq=round(I/LSB)`

I evaluate the noise of the quantized image as
`Iq_std_meas = std(Iq)`

**Case 1)**
If alpha>>0.5 then the signal swing is big compared to the LSB. I'm expecting to be able to model the output noise as `Iq_std_model = alpha+1/sqrt(12)` but it seems that a better model is `Iq_std_model = alpha` since the quantization error becomes insignificant.

**Case 2)**
If alpha<<0.5 I'm expecting to be able to model the output noise as such: `Iq_std_model = 1/sqrt(12)` but obviously Iq_std_meas tends to 0 the lower alpha becomes.

Note that for any value of alpha I can observe quantization noise as 1/sqrt(12) by just taking: `std(I-Iq)`

It seems I can't measure the final noise as `Iq_std_meas = std(Iq)`.
What is the fundamental point that I'm missing?

Comment: What kinda ADC is it?  If it's a ΣΔ ADC, the quantization noise will be sorta gaussian.  But if it's a *"conventional"* ADC, the quantization error will be uniform p.d.f.  I guess it looks like, from your code, that your model is of a conventional ADC.

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to model a conventional ADC (Iq=round(I/LSB) and hope it can be modeled using a gaussian approximation

Comment: That would be an inaccurate model.  It's a [uniform p.d.f.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) quantization error having zero mean (because you're using `round()` instead of `floor()`) with variance of $\frac{\Delta^2}{12}$ and it's bandlimited (to the Nyquist frequency) white.  Now, for most modeling purposes (such as noise shaping or something), it probably wouldn't hurt to replace the uniform p.d.f. with gaussian p.d.f. having the same mean and variance and spectrum (uncorrelated samples). If your signal swing is large, you can get away with it.

Comment: Thanks, how can I make the gaussian model work? Using alpha>>0.5 means that the signal swing is big compared to the quantization noise but when I calculate the std of the quantized image in such a scenario the value that I obtain is equal to alpha (the injected noise) and not alpha+1/sqrt(12).

Comment: I mean when you explicitly set your scenario to *not* look Gaussian, then it won't be possible to make it look Gaussian, @Knyq. Why do you *aim* to go for Gaussian? In the context of quantization noise, that's not very sensible, and is hence rarely done.

Comment: @MarcusMüller , suppose this was a conventional ADC using a conventional DAC in feedback to determine the quantization error (in the analog domain).  Then suppose some filter is being used to filter the quantization error before it is subtracted from the input to achieve noise-shaping of some form.  How are you going to model the output of that filtered quantization noise?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I think you're aiming for application of the central limit theorem and getting to Gaussian PDFs that way. It does get a bit ugly, though, for insufficiently dithered signals, because the CLT depends on *independently* identically distributed variables, and that quantization noise becomes correlated if there's few LSBs of change between the sales that get filtered!

Comment: I don't disagree.  I just think that when I have been doing noise-shaped quantization in the past, I knew the error coming out of the quantizer was uniform p.d.f. but I only worried about the mean and variance and filtered this just like it was AWGN with a bandwidth of Nyquist.  The behavior came out virtually the same as if it really **was** AWGN having the same mean and variance.

Comment: Stackexchange tradition is that if you answer your own question, rather than tacking it onto the end of the question section you actually file it as an answer.  You do this because, first, it _is_ the answer, and second, it lets people upvote it if it's good.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm expecting to be able to model the output noise as `Iq_std_model = alpha+1/sqrt(12)`

That's the big fundamental point that I was missing.
Standard deviation sums in quadrature, duh!
Using `Iq_std_model = sqrt(alpha^2+1/12)` works quite well when simulating Case1